# How CSS line-height is measured?

Tags: css

Is line-height in CSS goes from the bottom of the text to the bottom of the next line's text? or is text is vertically centered inside of the line?

Please see the example image:

[image]

Comment: From the W3 docs: `On a block container element whose content is composed of inline-level elements, 'line-height' specifies the minimal height of line boxes within the element. The minimum height consists of a minimum height above the baseline and a minimum depth below it, exactly as if each line box starts with a zero-width inline box with the element's font and line height properties. We call that imaginary box a "strut." (The name is inspired by TeX.).`

Comment: First example is what `line-height` behaves like

Comment: Left image is correct ;)

Comment: You will often see people use Line-Height to vertically align single line text inside of div's by setting the line-height to the same height as the div.

Comment: This question has actually blown my mind. I dont know WHO is right! haha - this article was a good read and I thought I would share it. http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/12/17/css-baseline-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly/

Comment: In future, please don't cross-post questions. Find the most appropriate site and stick to that one. I'll merge both of your questions here to consolidate the answers.

Answer (score 9):

[Form MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) :

> On block level elements, the line-height CSS property specifies the
>   minimal height of line boxes within the element.
>
> On non-replaced inline elements, line-height specifies the height that
>   is used in the calculation of the line box height.

As you can see in this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/NHDmT/)** and the folowing image. This means that for text, `line-height` defines the height of the box surounding the letters vertically centered inside that box so your **first example is right**.

[image]

*Image from [www.w3.org](http://www.w3.org/Talks/2008/0911-CSS-Amsterdam/)*

Answer (score 3):

As I already commented, the first example is what `line-height` actually behaves.

According to me, [image is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23247605/1542290), the `line-height` in the image is counted from baseline to baseline where as the `line-height` is counted on both the sides vertically, it's calculated by multiplying the number with elements `font-size`.

As an example, I've created a sample

```
div {
    outline: 1px solid #f00;
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/atjhm/)</kbd>

[image]

In the above example, the `line-height` acts like `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` property *(It's not really a padding)* and that's how it really works.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but as long as `line-height` defines the height of text line boxes and text of all the boxes is aligned verically within its box in the same way, it means that the `line-height` is the space between baselines.

Comment: [From the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height): ***Note.** When there is only one value of `line-height` for all inline boxes in a block container box and they are all in the same font (and there are no replaced elements, inline-block elements, etc.), the above will ensure that baselines of successive lines are exactly `line-height` apart.*

Answer (score 1):

Found this image, so it is your first example which is `line-height`

[image]

Comment: In your image, it shows line-height from the bottom of the first line letters to the bottom of second line letters so it looks more like the second example in the OP image

Comment: @web-tiki second example is *baseline*

Comment: damn, I confused myself now! I must look at OP's pic again.

Comment: Yea the pic is confusing

Comment: @Mr.Alien - I think web-tiki is probably right, from baseline to baseline is `line-height` ?

Comment: I don't think your image is right, for example with only one line of text, with a specific line-height, the box doesn't stop on the baseline see here http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/NHDmT/

Comment: @Mike I will answer, and yes, web tiki is right, the image is wrong

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems it's the first example showed in the image. Let's take this code:

### CSS

```
div {
    width:120px;
    height:30px;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
#box2 {
    line-height:30px;
}
#box3 {
    line-height:10px;
}
#box4 {
    line-height:60px;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div id="box1">No line-height</div>
<div id="box2">30px line-height</div>
<div id="box3">10px line-height</div>
<div id="box4">60px line-height</div>
```

Fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/58CJw/

It really seems that line-height is `fontSize + spaceAbove + spaceBelow`, where `spaceAbove` = `spaceBelow`.

Answer (score 0):

The [`line-height` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height) specifies the minimum height of line boxes, roughly speaking; the exact effect depends on the context (see the spec).

It is impossible to tell from the image what the real question is.

Comment: sorry - tihs is duplicate post. Here's my first post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247467/how-css-line-height-is-measured

Answer (score 0):

The line is vertically centered. This is why you can use `line-height` to vertically center one line elements.