# Add SVG (via CSS) that adjusts to element's font-size

Tags: css, svg, scale

I want to add an SVG via CSS, without any changes to the HTML.

**tl;dr:** The image should act like text.

The image should always have the height of the element (or even better, the text content) it gets added to, and the width according to its aspect ratio. The height/font-size/font-family of the element is not fixed (`height` is not specified, i.e., `auto`; `font-size` is specified in the `em` unit, and it can’t be relied on a specific default browser font-size; it should not depend on characteristics of a specific font).

The image should be added to the left of a heading (visually inside the heading’s box), and between the image and the heading content there should always be a spacing of `0.5em`.

Ideally it would work no matter what is specified in the SVG file (i.e., `width`/`height` on its `svg` element), but I’m fine with editing the SVG.

**Is this possible?**

I tried adding it as `background-image` (but how to get a spacing if the image width is unknown?), as pseudo-element within `content` (but how to adjust the width/height?), and as pseudo-element within `background-image` (but how to vertically align it with the text, and how to make it appear without specifying only height in `em` or similar?).

I’m open to any solution that the newest browser versions support.

[Example SVG](https://gist.github.com/unor/f60ef0ee90218560067e)

```css
h1 {font-size:1.5em;}

.foo {
  background-image:url("noun_39107.svg");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:contain;
  /* … but how to get a spacing of 0.5em, no matter the size? */
}

.bar::before {
  content:url("noun_39107.svg");
  margin-right:0.5em;
  /* … but how to scale it? */
}

.qux::before {
  content:" ";
  margin-right:0.5em;
  background-image:url("noun_39107.svg");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:contain;
  display:inline-block;
  height:1em; width:1em; /* … I don’t know the actual height/width */
  vertical-align:middle;
  /* … but how to align it vertically so that it’s like text? */
}
```

```html
<h1 class="foo">Foo</h1>

<h1 class="bar">Bar</h1>

<h1 class="qux">Qux</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this

```css
h1 {font-size:1.5em;}
h1.lg {font-size:4em;}

.qux::before {
  content:" ";
  margin-right:0.5em;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;dataset=utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><path d="M95.71 50c0-1.218-6.9-.794-7.502-1.92-.575-1.112 5.03-4.672 4.723-5.8-.313-1.137-6.96-1.37-7.015-2.612-.048-1.256 6.304-4.104 5.777-5.178-.52-1.078-6.77 2.04-7.7 1.19-.932-.852 3.312-5.886 2.73-6.902s-7.084.168-7.345-1.064c-.273-1.24 5.538-5.106 4.867-6.09-.685-.988-6.305 3.088-7.365 2.42-1.063-.663 2.072-6.522 1.252-7.364-.815-.85-6.73 2.2-7.393 1.146-.687-1.074 3.154-6.82 2.106-7.427-1.047-.606-4.113 5.585-5.387 5.54-1.24-.048-1.562-6.694-2.704-6.985-1.137-.28-4.635 5.363-5.743 4.774-1.11-.586-.377-7.493-1.58-7.585-1.172-.09-1.638 6.883-2.842 7.263-1.197.38-3.413-5.843-4.606-5.843-1.184 0-3.407 6.223-4.593 5.843-1.21-.38-1.66-7.352-2.838-7.263-1.2.092-.486 7-1.59 7.584-1.115.588-4.606-5.056-5.74-4.772-1.154.29-1.47 6.937-2.704 6.985-1.284.044-4.342-6.147-5.39-5.54-1.042.604 2.792 6.354 2.105 7.43-.664 1.053-6.57-2-7.38-1.154-.822.84 2.312 6.7 1.254 7.364-1.06.667-6.685-3.41-7.36-2.42-.683.982 5.127 4.85 4.86 6.09-.268 1.23-6.758.043-7.347 1.063-.585 1.013 3.66 6.054 2.72 6.906-.932.846-7.174-2.266-7.694-1.19-.52 1.078 5.827 3.915 5.777 5.174-.04 1.243-6.688 1.468-7.004 2.608-.317 1.13 5.29 4.696 4.713 5.808-.586 1.12-7.482.7-7.482 1.917 0 1.222 6.904.794 7.486 1.916.577 1.113-5.03 4.676-4.714 5.805.317 1.142 6.957 1.377 7.004 2.606.042 1.27-6.303 4.11-5.78 5.178.523 1.082 6.762-2.033 7.695-1.188.94.855-3.306 5.89-2.722 6.906.59 1.023 7.077-.168 7.35 1.068.27 1.238-5.54 5.103-4.862 6.085.676.996 6.3-3.08 7.36-2.417 1.064.664-2.075 6.52-1.252 7.362.827.853 6.725-2.204 7.39-1.157.687 1.075-3.148 6.832-2.103 7.43 1.05.606 4.115-5.595 5.39-5.54 1.24.048 1.56 6.7 2.71 6.985 1.134.294 4.628-5.35 5.737-4.76 1.102.574.38 7.487 1.586 7.576 1.17.086 1.63-6.875 2.842-7.26 1.193-.38 3.413 5.847 4.6 5.847 1.186 0 3.403-6.23 4.602-5.845 1.204.384 1.656 7.34 2.84 7.26 1.205-.097.486-7.007 1.59-7.585 1.107-.592 4.605 5.048 5.735 4.764 1.15-.294 1.465-6.934 2.703-6.98 1.287-.042 4.347 6.145 5.394 5.54 1.04-.593-2.793-6.355-2.115-7.43.67-1.048 6.57 2.01 7.398 1.156.814-.84-2.313-6.698-1.26-7.362 1.062-.663 6.682 3.413 7.366 2.424.67-.982-5.135-4.854-4.868-6.092.274-1.236 6.77-.052 7.358-1.07.575-1.018-3.67-6.05-2.725-6.904.924-.84 7.16 2.283 7.68 1.194.527-1.078-5.824-3.915-5.77-5.185.04-1.232 6.694-1.465 7.016-2.605.31-1.13-5.297-4.682-4.722-5.8.583-1.115 7.482-.698 7.482-1.92zm-59.437 1.48c-5.137 0-9.3-4.166-9.3-9.3 0-5.137 4.163-9.302 9.3-9.302 5.138 0 9.3 4.165 9.3 9.302 0 5.133-4.162 9.3-9.3 9.3zm27.053 0c-5.133 0-9.295-4.166-9.295-9.3 0-5.137 4.163-9.302 9.296-9.302 5.14 0 9.303 4.165 9.303 9.302 0 5.133-4.163 9.3-9.304 9.3zM36.273 38.675c-1.932 0-3.5 1.57-3.5 3.505 0 1.93 1.568 3.5 3.5 3.5 1.934 0 3.503-1.57 3.503-3.5 0-1.934-1.57-3.505-3.503-3.505zM63.326 38.675c-1.93 0-3.497 1.57-3.497 3.505 0 1.93 1.566 3.5 3.496 3.5 1.938 0 3.505-1.57 3.505-3.5 0-1.934-1.566-3.505-3.504-3.505z"/></svg>');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  height:1em;
  width:1em;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="qux">Qux</h1>
<h1 class="qux lg">Qux</h1>
```

Comment: It does not seem to be aligned exactly, or is it only me? I added outlines and made a [**screenshot**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xSlLx.png) of how it renders for me.

Comment: @unor it depends on font, read something about css line-height http://stackoverflow.com/a/23247997/2958320, see selection http://cl.ly/ZtZl, try another font, or change .qux::before height as you need, may be `height:1.2em;`