# Cannot remove padding/margin in CSS

Tags: css, sass

I have an HTML structure like this:

```
<div id='root'>
  <div class='tile-row'>
    <div class='tile'></div>
    <div class='tile'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='tile-row'>
    <div class='tile'></div>
    <div class='tile'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are actually 10 tile rows and 10 tiles per row.

I'm styling with the following sass:

```
body, html
  overflow-x: scroll
  padding: 0
  margin: 0
  background-color: black
  color: white

.tile-row
  display: block
  margin: 0
  padding: 0

.tile
  display: inline-block
  outline: 1px solid white
  width: 10px
  height: 10px
```

The problem is that there is a border/margin between the rows I'm not sure how to get rid of. I want the cells to be right up against each other. [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xjGjNO) is a codepen of it. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `line-height: 0` to your `.tile-row` or change its display to something other than `inline-block` (for example, to any `table-*` or `grid` or `flex` display).

The explanation:

From the CSS specifation available at https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height

> As described in the section on inline formatting contexts, user agents
>   flow inline-level boxes into a vertical stack of line boxes. The
>   height of a line box is determined as follows:
>
> The height of each inline-level box in the line box is calculated. For
>   replaced elements, inline-block elements, and inline-table elements,
>   this is the height of their margin box; for inline boxes, this is
>   their 'line-height'. (See "Calculating heights and margins" and the
>   height of inline boxes in "Leading and half-leading".)
>
> The inline-level boxes are aligned vertically according to their
>   'vertical-align' property. In case they are aligned 'top' or 'bottom',
>   they must be aligned so as to minimize the line box height. If such
>   boxes are tall enough, there are multiple solutions and CSS 2.1 does
>   not define the position of the line box's baseline (i.e., the position
>   of the strut, see below).
>
> The line box height is the distance between the uppermost box top and
>   the lowermost box bottom. (This includes the strut, as explained under
>   'line-height' below.)
>
> Empty inline elements generate empty inline boxes, but these boxes
>   still have margins, padding, borders and a line height, and thus
>   influence these calculations just like elements with content.

and in other parts of the spec:

> inline-block This value causes an element to generate an inline-level
>   block container. The inside of an inline-block is formatted as a block
>   box, and the element itself is formatted as an atomic inline-level
>   box.

and:

> Inline-level elements are those elements of the source document that
>   do not form new blocks of content; the content is distributed in lines

The conclusion is that the inline-block tiles count as really big characters, and line height just affects them by making the lines slightly larger than the characters are.

Relevant links:

- [How CSS line-height is measured?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247467/how-css-line-height-is-measured)
- https://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

Comment: `line-height` affects text baseline. do you mean `height`?

Comment: I clearly meant line-height. Changing font-size would work too, but would kill anything written inside the .title-row if the OP wants to write anything in it. Edit: The point is that the inline-block tiles count as _really big characters_, and line height just affects them by making the lines slightly larger than the characters are, though don't take my word on that.

Comment: `line-height` affects text, not cell positioning. OP hasn't mentioned text being placed in the `.tile` elements. How does this answer work?

Comment: The .tiles themselves are text for the .tile-row, since they're inline-block, you can check the specification for the details. Or you can just go ahead and add it to the JSFiddle and see that it works.

Comment: Edited my answer to provide an in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 2):

use `display:table-cell` for your `.tile`

```
.tile
  display: inline-block
  outline: 1px solid white
  width: 20px
  height: 20px
  display: table-cell
```

[pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zjGaoK)

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears from `display: inline-block` another solution might be `font-size: 0;` or display: `flex` instead of `inline-block`

```
.tile-row
  display: block
  margin: 0
  padding: 0
  font-size: 0
```

Don't forget to set back the font size for `.tile` in case you use `font-size: 0` solution.

Answer (score 1):

Although adjusting your line height may help, since you know how big your grid is width wise, you can set a width to the grid itself and then force the elements to float to the left. Knowing each cell is 20x20, the grid would then have a max width of 200. Here's my solution for your grid:

```
  .tile-row
      display: block
      margin: 0
      padding: 0
      max-width: 200px

  .tile
      display: inline-block
      float: left
      outline: 1px solid white
      width: 20px
      height: 20px
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try:

```
position: relative
float: left
margin: 0
padding: 0
```

If it's still not working, you may have some other css code affecting your element. You can override it with !important eg: `margin: 0 !important`.

Good luck!